# Tkinter frames container inside a PanedWindow

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I have a Tkinter app, where the left side of a `PanedWindow` uses a frames container as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter), and the right side has a `ScrolledText` used for logging as described [here](https://beenje.github.io/blog/posts/logging-to-a-tkinter-scrolledtext-widget/). I'm also using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35991126/tkinter-frame-resize) to resize the frames in the frames container, as they have different sizes.

My problem is that whenever a different frame is showed using the `show_frame(..)` method from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter), the right side (the `ScrolledText`) doesn't resize to match the new frame size and overrides the left frame content.

This is the code part that constructs the `PanedWindow` and frames container.

```
class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", self.on_closing)
        self.geometry('1366x768')
        self.resizable(True, True)
        self.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        # Horizontal pane
        self.horizontal_pane = tk.PanedWindow(self, orient=HORIZONTAL)
        self.horizontal_pane.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky="nsew")
        # Frames container
        self.container = tk.Frame(self.horizontal_pane)
        self.horizontal_pane.add(self.container)
        # Log frame
        self.console_frame = tk.Frame(self.horizontal_pane)
        self.console_frame.columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.console_frame.rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
        self.horizontal_pane.add(self.console_frame, stretch='always')
```

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 0):

I managed to solve it by editing the `show_frame()` method:

```
def show_frame(self, page_name):
    for frame in self.frames.values():
        frame.grid_remove()
    self.horizontal_pane.grid_remove() # Add this
    frame = self.frames[page_name]
    frame.grid()
    self.horizontal_pane.grid() # And that
```

Not sure if that's the right way though, but now whenever a new frame is shown, the `ScrolledText` on the right side is resized to match the left frame size.